# Spring Cloud Gateway and NGINX

Tags: nginx, oauth, reverse-proxy, spring-cloud-gateway

Do I still need NGINX to serve static content like JS etc and reverse proxy request to backend, or it can be done with just Spring Cloud Gateway? 
Spring docs has a following image:

[image]

And I found no description there on how to return static content to the client, does it mean it's considered bad practice and I need extra step of reverse proxying adding its latency?
If not, where can I find more info on how to do that with Spring Cloud Gateway, especially if I'm going to make oauth2 authorization-code flow authentication using Spring Gateway?

Answer (score 2):

I am using NGINX as reverse proxy, but i thought about the same question and i tried (same thing for me. oauth2 authorization-code flow authentication). So, you can serve static content with just Spring Cloud Gateway, it is possible.

For example if you are using React, take build and copy all build files to under resources/static/frontend-name location. Then, disable (permitAll) web security in that all frontend locations. So you can access just typing http://gatewayserver/frontend-name/index.html

However, I don't think to use it in production environment, NGINX still sounds like better idea for me. Because when I take release for frontends, why do i need to take release for gateway at the same time or vice-versa? But, if you have small project, it might be an option.